# Can we export an HTML Page to a PDF without disturbing the links?

Tags: pdf, html

I am looking to covert an HTML page to a PDF and wanted to have some expert advice.
The sample of the HTML page is [here](https://www.srishtiindia.com/teamlease)

Comment: What happens when you print the browser screen but export to PDF instead printing?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Adobe Acrobat Pro, you can create a PDF straight from a webpage.

Open Acrobat, then Create > Create PDF from Web Page
[image]

Then enter the web address of the page you want to create a PDF for.
[image]

All the links should stay intact.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, most browsers will let you print the page.  And there is normally an option to print to a pdf file.

If it doesnt show this option then you can install programs such as [Cutepdf](https://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) or [Win2Pdf](https://www.win2pdf.com/pdf-printer-driver.html).

On Linux one can use `cups-pdf` package